# Multiples document s types refinementfilters

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i am using rest api search to get documents with certain extensions types.

I am having this code:

```
&refinementfilters=or'(fileExtension:equals("aspx"),fileExtension:equals("wmv"))'
```

The whole code is:

```
https://myUrl/_api/search/query?selectproperties='Path,Url,Title,Size,IsDocument,PictureUrl,LastModifiedTime'&querytext='wildlife'&refinementfilters= '(fileExtension:equals("aspx"))'
```

i would like to use rest api refinementfilters fileExtension using or, but the syntax with the OR condition doesn' t work, can you halp me point out
where the problem can be ?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To apply multiple filters via `refinementfilters` property, replace

```
refinementfilters='(fileExtension:equals("aspx"))'
```

with

```
refinementfilters='fileExtension:or("aspx","wmv")'
```

**Example**

```
/_api/search/query?selectproperties='Path,Url,Title,Size,IsDocument,PictureUrl,LastModifiedTime'&querytext='*'&refinementfilters= 'fileExtension:or("docx","pdf")'
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as general syntax, the quotes for the OR are in the wrong place:

Original version:

```
&refinementfilters=or'(fileExtension:equals("aspx"),fileExtension:equals("wmv"))'
```

Corrected version:

```
&refinementfilters='or(fileExtension:equals("aspx"),fileExtension:equals("wmv"))'
```